# Creating a volume slider for VLCJ audio

Tags: java, swing, gradient

I am trying to create an volume level bar where different level's of volume are represented with an different color here is my approach

I have 2 arrays

`Color[]` scales gives different color representation for each volume level if the length of this array is lets say 4 then there are 4 volume level's and so on

`float[]` weights denotes how much percentage/space each color should occupy in the bar

For example

```
private final Color scales[]={Color.GREEN,Color.YELLOW,Color.RED};
private final float weights[]={0.3f,0.2f,0.5f};
```

means there are 3 levels of volume where

1. if the current volume is <=30% of max then 30% of the volume bar is covered in GREEN
2. if the current volume is >30% and <= (30+20)=50% the next 20% of the volume bar is covered in YELLOW
3. if the current volume is >50% and <= (50+50)=100% the final 50% of the volume bar is covered in RED

Now the user interacts with the volume bar by clicking & dragging the mouse hence let' say if the volume bar has dimensions (x=120,y=50) and lets say I click or drag till Xposition=25 then

```
30% of 120=36

XPosition=25

25<36 hence must draw an green color rect of dimensions x=0,y=0,width=36-25=12,height=50
```

and we continue likewise for the remaining positions calculating where the user clicks and drawing different color rectangles till that point.

Now I think I butchered the explanation but I am not asking for the code I already have it implemented here

```
final class VolumeBar extends JPanel 
{
 VolumeBar()
 {
  super(new BorderLayout());
  
  add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(500,100)),BorderLayout.NORTH);
  
  add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(500,100)),BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  
  JPanel container=new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
  
  container.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(120,50)),BorderLayout.WEST);
  
  container.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(120,50)),BorderLayout.EAST);
  
  container.add(new JVolume(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
  
  add(container,BorderLayout.CENTER);
 }
 
 private final class JVolume extends JLabel
 {
  private final Color scales[]={Color.GREEN,Color.YELLOW,Color.RED};
  private final float weights[]={0.6f,0.2f,0.2f};
  private int endingX;
  
  private JVolume()
  {
   addMouseMotionListener(new Drag());
   
   addMouseListener(new Click());
   
   setPreferredSize(new Dimension(260,50));
  }
  
  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
   super.paintComponent(g);
   
   Graphics2D g2d=(Graphics2D)g;
   Dimension size=getSize();
  
  
   float endPoints[]=new float[scales.length+1];
   endPoints[0]=0;
   for(int i=1;i<endPoints.length;i++){endPoints[i]=endPoints[i-1]+(size.width*weights[i-1]);}
   
   for(int i=1;i<endPoints.length;i++)
   {
    float
    prev=endPoints[i-1],
    current=endPoints[i];
     
    if(endingX>prev) 
    {
     g2d.setColor(scales[i-1]);
  
     g2d.fill(new Rectangle2D.Float(prev,0,endingX>current?current-prev:endingX-prev,size.height));       
    }
    else{break;}
   }
   
   g2d.setColor(getBackground());
   Polygon clear=new Polygon();
   clear.addPoint(0,0);
   clear.addPoint(size.width,0);
   clear.addPoint(0,size.height);
   clear.addPoint(0,0);
   g2d.fill(clear);  //clear the upper left triangle with background to make it look like an increasing triangle
   
   g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);  draw the lower right triangle to give the bar some border
   Polygon polygon=new Polygon();
   polygon.addPoint(1,size.height-1);
   polygon.addPoint(size.width-1,1);
   polygon.addPoint(size.width-1,size.height-1);
   polygon.addPoint(1,size.height-1);
   g2d.drawPolygon(polygon);
  }
  
  private void compute(MouseEvent m)
  {
   endingX=m.getX();
   
   repaint();
  }
  
  private final class Drag extends MouseMotionAdapter
  {
   @Override
   public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent m){compute(m);}
  }

  private final class Click extends MouseAdapter
  {
   @Override
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent m){compute(m);}
  }
 }
}
```

And here is how it look's like just click or drag anywhere on the bar

[image: Volume Bar]

Look's great for the most part but what I am aiming for is the volume bar in VLC media player

[image]

Forgive the blurriness, I had to scale the image up but if you look closely you can notice how the color's blend at the boundary for example there is an gradient from green->yellow making some white in between at the boundary and there is an gradient from yellow->red making some orange in between

I want to achieve this gradient.

Ideas anyone?

Comment: Use a [`MultipleGradientPaint`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/MultipleGradientPaint.html).

Comment: Which one linear or radial? I have never worked with these paints before so please help me out here

Comment: A linear one should do, a radial one goes from the center till the end of a circle.

Comment: Well, did you look at the images as **shown in the in the Java Docs of each**? *"help me out here"* "Give a man a fish.."

Comment: The thing is I tried with these paints before asking here. LinearGradient requires the weights to be in increasing order otherwise I get an illegal argument exception but from my example you can see my weights are the exact opposite and radial doesn't fit my purpose at all. I need a more *exotic fish*

Comment: *"LinearGradient requires the weights to be in increasing order otherwise I get an illegal argument exception but from my example you can see my weights are the exact opposite"* .. are you *sure* programming is for you? *"I need a more exotic fish"* Or in this case, basic skills in subtraction.

Comment: I need 60% of my bar in green then 20% in yellow not the other way around which is what LinearGradient requires.you see why it's a problem now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As recommended by @AndrewThompson in the comments above you can use [`MultipleGradientPaint`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/MultipleGradientPaint.html) using a `LinearGradientPaint`.

Currently I'm confused by which of the 2 you need, above you said:

> 1. if the current volume is <=30% of max then 30% of the volume bar is covered in GREEN
> 2. if the current volume is >30% and <= (30+20)=50% the next 20% of the volume bar is covered in YELLOW
> 3. if the current volume is >50% and <= (50+50)=100% the final 50% of the volume bar is covered in RED

And then you said:

> I need 60% of my bar in green then 20% in yellow not the other way around which is what LinearGradient requires.you see why it's a problem now?

But those are just numbers.

What you can do is create your `LinearGradientPaint` this way:

```
Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(10, 10, 250, 150);

Point2D startPoint = new Point2D.Double(rect.getMinX(), rect.getCenterY());
Point2D endPoint = new Point2D.Double(rect.getMaxX(), rect.getCenterY());
float[] percentages = new float[] {0.0f, 0.6f, 0.8f};
Color[] colors = new Color[] {Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW, Color.RED};
        
LinearGradientPaint gradient = new LinearGradientPaint(startPoint, endPoint, percentages, colors, CycleMethod.REPEAT);
```

You were confused at where you need to start the gradient because I guess your percentages were: `0.6f, 0.2f, 0.2f` but instead you need to define the start point and then add the next percentage from there, `0.0f, 0.6f, 0.8f` (This will start at 0% then go up to 60% to green, and then up to 80% to yellow, and then the rest to 100% on red.

And you get this output.

[image]

---

**MRE** for you to test changes:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.LinearGradientPaint;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.MultipleGradientPaint.CycleMethod;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class LinearGradientExample {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel pane;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new LinearGradientExample()::createAndShowGUI);
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());
        
        Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(10, 10, 250, 150);
        Point2D startPoint = new Point2D.Double(rect.getMinX(), rect.getCenterY());
        Point2D endPoint = new Point2D.Double(rect.getMaxX(), rect.getCenterY());
        float[] percentages = new float[] {0.0f, 0.6f, 0.8f};
        Color[] colors = new Color[] {Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW, Color.RED};
        
        LinearGradientPaint gradient = new LinearGradientPaint(startPoint, endPoint, percentages, colors, CycleMethod.REPEAT);
        
        pane = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                
                g2d.setPaint(gradient);
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                g2d.fill(rect);
            }
            
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(300, 200);
            }
        };
        
        frame.add(pane);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see now. I thought we were talking about left over percentage values so I really was confused. I would upvote this twice if I could thank you

Comment: But I do have one question why have you used getCenterY()? If I were to just use miny=0 and maxY=getSize(). height what would be the difference?

Comment: I posted the whole code, give it a try and see what happens. There's no difference, I just started that way and that's it. As it's repeating itself there's no difference on which one you use.